# Can't delete relationships nor nodes in neo4j after commit failed

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was trying to import 10 million relationships across around 8 million nodes to neo4j, but the transaction failed because of my machine run out of disk space.

However, there are certain amount of relationships imported because of periodic commit. And after that I get following error

```
While loading relationships for Node[28941481] a
Relationship[101654465] was encountered that had startNode:
28941479 and endNode: 28941478,
i.e. which had neither start nor end node as the node we're loading relationships for
```

when I try to query like

```
MATCH ()-[r:MY_RELATION]->() RETURN r LIMIT 25;
```

I tried to delete the node and relationship mentioned in the error message, but seems I can't delete either of them.

So I'm wondering if I need to clean the disk and import everything again or is there anyway that I can fix my current DB?

Update:

Import statement

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///tmp/file" AS csvLine
MATCH (e:Entity {id:toInt(csvLine.entity_id)}),(o:Other {id: toInt(csvLine.other_id)})
CREATE (e)-[:MY_RELATION {orderID:toInt(csvLine.last_id), TypeID:toInt(csvLine.ttid), state:csvLine.state}]->(other)
```

Comment: Where did that error message come from?  Your code or something else?  Also, what does your load code look like?   I can't tell much about the nodes or the relationships from this example, only that they exist.

Comment: What are the periodic commit settings?   Please post your `IMPORT CSV` code.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits thanks for your reply, I have updated my import csv code

Comment: Maybe the relationship direction will be wrong as you mention the query, please verify once.

Comment: OP, what is `pax` in your import statement?  This looks like a possible error to me, since it's not bound in a `MATCH` clause.  Basically pax is a new, anonymous node, probably not what you intend.   Also, where did that error message come from?   The part where it says `i.e. which had neither...` doesn't look like something cypher output, so I'm wondering if you have some other code that's saying that, or doing something else.

Comment: sorry `pax` is a typo.. I have updated the query